# Does phpstorm support hhvm as php language setting?

Tags: php, phpstorm, hhvm

I was just wondering why some code of mine wouldn't work:

```
./vendor/bin/phpunit -c tests/phpunit-no-coverage.xml tests/ --filter=Env
PHPUnit 4.8.19 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Runtime:    HHVM 3.6.1
Configuration:  /var/www/le-project/tests/phpunit-no-coverage.xml


Fatal error: Call to undefined function unit\Service\yaml_parse() in /var/www/le-project/tests/unit/Service/SomeTraitTest.php on line 43
```

Then it hit me: I am using [hhvm, which doesn't support `yaml_parse`](http://docs.hhvm.com/manual/en/function.yaml-parse.php).

I know I can set the langauge setting from 5.3..7:

[image: PHP Language Settings in phpstorm]

Yet does phpstorm support hhvm as a language setting as well, so it will warn me inside the IDE which functions are supported or not?

Comment: Loosely related: [Hack Language Support in PhpStorm Postponed](http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2015/06/hack-language-support-in-phpstorm-postponed/)

Comment: 1) All supported PHP language levels are already in the list; 2) PhpStorm does not support Hack language; 3) Will your tests run fine if you execute them outside of IDE? 4) Based on the command line I may say that it's not executed by PhpStorm (although I may be wrong here as I prefer PHAR version of PHPUnit). 5) The error .. and your comment tell me that this method is not supported by actual HHVM and therefore I'm failing to see PhpStorm issue here.